# How to see the client_registration strings of the connected Oracle-clients?

Tags: oracle, sqlnet

Because we run multiple instances of the same application on the dev-servers, I'm trying to add the `sqlnet.client_registration`-parameter to the `sqlnet.ora`-files used by each instance. This, I hope, would help us distinguish clients by the instance-name instead of (or in addition to) hostname:

```
sqlnet.client_registration=MeowMeow
```

However, I do not see the configured strings anywhere in the `V$SESSION` -- is there some other place to look for the "MeowMeow" from the above example?

Comment: `client_registration` appears in the audit trail, not v$session

Comment: Potentially you could modify your app code to call the `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO` procedure. That will allow up to a 64 byte identifier to be placed into `V$SESSION`. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.html#GUID-68A3DF04-BE91-46CC-8D2B-97BA0E89956F

Answer (score 0):

1. This parameter is valid for the client, not the server. Configuring it on the server side makes no sense.
2. The extra information is displayed in the listener log, and it does not appear in audit trail nor `V$SESSION`.

Comment: I am talking about the client-side `sqlnet.ora` -- multiple application-instances talk to the same server, and I'd like to make it easier for us to distinguish the connections.

Comment: @MikhailT. Ok, then as suggested, use `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO`.

Comment: Not an option, unfortunately -- this is a closed-source application from an external software vendor...